# Difference between KEYBOARD_PRESS and VIRTUAL_KEY

Tags: android, haptic-feedback

I'm implementing a virtual Android keyboard and are about to add haptic feedback. Luckily Android provides [`performHapticFeedback()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performHapticFeedback(int)) and [`HapticFeedbackConstants`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html) so it's easy to give the user a haptic feedback.

It's however not clear to me what the difference between [`KEYBOARD_PRESS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html#KEYBOARD_PRESS) and [`VIRTUAL_KEY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html#VIRTUAL_KEY) is, they both seem to represent pressing a virtual key. This is also the case for their counterparts [`KEYBOARD_RELEASE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html#KEYBOARD_RELEASE) and [`VIRTUAL_KEY_RELEASE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html#VIRTUAL_KEY_RELEASE) which both seems to represent the user release a virtual key.

I found [the commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/262dadf8708b5ecc80bccee14adf587f2fb2e4d5) where the newest ones were added (in API 27) but that unfortunally didn't clarify anything. The documentation states the following:

> `KEYBOARD_PRESS` (Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003))
>
> The user has pressed a virtual or software keyboard key.
>
> `VIRTUAL_KEY` (Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001))
>
> The user has pressed on a virtual on-screen key.

[`KEYBOARD_TAP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html#KEYBOARD_TAP) maybe also makes sense to mention, but it has the same value [`KEYBOARD_PRESS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html#KEYBOARD_PRESS) so I think it's more obvious that they represent the same thing. For completeness it's documentation is:

> `KEYBOARD_TAP` (Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003))
>
> The user has pressed a soft keyboard key.